# Creating T4 template file referring SubSonic

Tags: subsonic3, t4

I am trying to write T4 template to create wrapper classes for classes created by SubSonic 3 (implementing IActiveRecord). But when I compile my template I get following error:

```
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'SubSonic.Core' could not be found
```

I'm including SubSonic.Core in my settings file. `<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core" #>` and then importing the namespaces like `<#@ import namespace="SubSonic.Schema"#>` and `<#@ import namespace="SubSonic"#>`

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need to put SubSonic.Core.dll into GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting `.dll` at the end of the assembly name?

```
<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core.dll" #>
```

(Make sure that SubSonic.Core.dll is in the same directory).

There is an article on the T4 Assembly directive that may help you:

```
http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-assembly-directive/
```

Comment: thanks @kragen I'd also figured it from same page :D
Oleg is fantastic!!