# T4 templates in VS 2010 Cannot Find Metada file SubSonic.Core.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, subsonic3, t4

I am using Subsonic 3 to generate DAL. Further I am using T4 templates to generate my BOs from DAL. Subsonic's T4 templates are working properly, but when I run my templates it gives me following error:

```
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'SubSonic.Core.dll' could not be found
```

I have imported SubSonic in my `settings.include` file like this:

```
<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core.dll" #>
```

I am referring `SubSonic.Core` project (I've downloaded code). SubSonic is not installed in GAC, but DAL project is generating code just file like this.

EDIT 1:- If I remove `<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core.dll" #>` it new error crops up:

```
Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'SubSonic' could not be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

EDIT 2:- I have got solution to this problem by adding `<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core.dll" #>` as suggested in answer to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385501/creating-t4-template-file-referring-subsonic) question, but that was in VS 2008. Don't know why this is not working in VS 2010.

EDIT 3:- Installed SubSonic.Core.dll to GAC, restarted VS, still getting the freaking error. Should have slept instead.

Comment: @Henk there is a link to the question where I got the first solution.

Comment: Does it actually say "SubSonc.Core.dll", or is it "SubSonic.Core.dll"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After beating my head against the wall for quite a long time, I installed SubSonic.Core.dll into GAC. Then I removed .dll from

```
<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core.dll" #>
```

and changed it to

```
<#@ assembly name="SubSonic.Core" #>
```

now working fine.